# I have tried to get jquery show/hide and attr dislay to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a single html page site with jquery to show and hide divs, immitate the idea of there being multiple pages. I have tried the show hide method and the address bar link changes but the divs do not change. I went back to the .attr("style", "display: block"); method and still not working. I put some of the divs I am trying to show and hide in this post but did not put them all to keep the post shorter. I did this feature before in another project so followed the steps to the working one but does not seem to want to work with this project. I am coding in Adobe Brackets but I have tried this in dreamweaver and sublime and still get the same issue. I am not sure if it is because the bootstrap is messing with it or that i am missing something small.

```js
<script>
$(Document).ready(function(){ //main menu Home
    $("#navHome").click(function(event){
       $("#home").attr("style", "display: block");
       $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
       $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       
           /*$("#home").show();
            $("#primalkb, #primalstr, #about, #fighttraining, #location, #kidsMA, #schedule, #freetr").hide();*/
});
    $("#navPrimalkb").click(function(event){
            $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: block");
            $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
            $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       
           
        });
    ("#navPrimalstr").click(function(event){
        $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: block");
        $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       

    });
    $("#navKidsma").click(function(event){
        $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: block");
        $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       

    });
    $("#navMMA").click(function(event){
        $("#mma").attr("style", "display: block");
        $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       

    });
    $("#navSchedule").click(function(event){
        $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: block");
        $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: none");       
    });
    $("#navFreetr").click(function(event){
        $("#freetr").attr("style", "display: block");
        $("#home").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalstr").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#mma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#kidsma").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#location").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#schedule").attr("style", "display: none");
        $("#primalkb").attr("style", "display: none");
    });
});
    </script>
```

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link hre="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-------------Scripts--------------------------->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.custom.24059.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    </head>
   <!-- <style>
        #linkings {
color: limegreen;
            text-decoration-color: limegreen;
        }
    </style>-->
    <body>
        <div id="bckg" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" width="150" alt="primal kickboxing logo"></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-rght">
                        <li class=""><a class="links" id="navHome" rel="home" href="#">HOME</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Classes<b class="caret"></b></a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="links" id="navPrimalkb" rel="primal kickboxing" href="#primalkb">Primak Kickboxing</a></li>   
                        <li><a class="links" id="navPrimalstr" rel="primal strength" href="#primalstr">Primal Strength Training</a></li>   
                        <li><a class="links" id="navKidsma" rel="kidsmma" href="#kidsma">Kids Martial Arts</a></li>    
                        <li><a id="navMMA" class="links" rel="mma" href="#mma">MMA Training</a></li>
                       </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="navSchedule" rel="schedule" class="links" href="#sch">SCHEDULE</a></li>
                        <li><a id="navLocation" class="links" rel="location" href="#location">LOCATION</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
      
      <!---------------Home----------------------------->
    <div id="home" style="display: block">
        <h1>ssx kj</h1>            
    </div>
<!--------------Class---------------------------->
   <!-- <div id="class" style="display:none"> 
        
    </div>-->
    <!---------------subfight class----------------------------->
    <!---Kickboxing------------>
        <div id="primalkb" style="display: none">
            <h1>s46545646s</h1>
        </div>
    <!---Strength Training---->
        <div id="primalstr" style="display:none">
            <h1>ssdjvkss</h1>
        </div>
    <!--Kids Martial Arts----->
        <div id="kidsma" style="display: none">
            <h1>sjsdfs</h1>
        </div>
    <!-----Fight Training----->
        <div id="mma" style="display: none">
            <h1>sqs</h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: So what actually doesn't work? I would advise you to use classes so you could hide all your 'pages' at once.

Comment: The divs do not change. in each div i just hit random keys to test and see if they change but it stays on the home div with the style display: block

Comment: You say that the address bar changes? So you are actually reloading the page or not?

Comment: no just in the address bar it displaces a loopback ip cause i am running it on brackets and then at the end if i click home it has #navHome or if i click schedule it has #navSchedule but the div for everything but home does not display. all the divs other than home are set to display:none and then in the jquery script you can see i set the functions for on clicks to change the div that is displayed. the page never reloads it is all loaded when you open the page since it is a single page

Comment: Well maybe it would help if you open your browsers console so you can see you have some errors. You should have `$(document).ready` instead of `$(Document).ready`. JavaScript is case-sensitive. Secondly you have an error on your third click event: `("#navPrimalstr").click(` should be `$("#navPrimalstr").click(`. Other than that, it works fine I think: http://jsfiddle.net/yeoy8e6d/

Comment: Thank you. I have been working on a bunch of sites this week so I think I have been looking at a screen for too long

Answer (score 0):

try this code it can help you

```
$("#navPrimalkb").click(function(event){
     $("#mma").css("display", "block");
   //$("#exm").css("display", "none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have the id of the anchor you can use `$('#ID').hide()` to hide it and to show it use `$('#ID').show()`